# VueJs - Is there any sample of using VueJs with new webpack 4 setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Now in VueJs template there are many sample and skeleton for starters projects. But all of them still using webpack v3. Is there anyone have been play with webpack 4 ? Like to see how you implement v4 of webpack to VueJs project.

Thanks

Comment: See - https://medium.com/@nupoor_neha/starting-with-webpack-4-and-vuejs-a-quick-start-tutorial-4a244410d55e

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Vue-cli's webpack4 branch](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/webpack4).

This is a branch in vue-cli which contains configuration for webpack4. But it is still in beta stage and may contain bug.